# Memory Allocation - Addresses in multiple of 4

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I need to allocate 4 byte memory and the allocated memory address should be the multiple of 4.
eg:400, 404,408,40c

If I use any memory allocation function, I receive memory which are available and the addresses are not necessarily be in multiples of 4.

So can anyone suggest to achieve this design.

Comment: `malloc` is guaranteed to be aligned properly for whatever you use it for, so unless all your basic types are less than 4 bytes (unlikely) this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Microsoft C/C++ compiller you can use [_aligned_malloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and in Linux [posix_memalign](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html) .

**MSVC:**

```
ptr = _aligned_malloc(4, 4);
```

Signature:

```
void * _aligned_malloc(size_t size, size_t alignment);
```

**Linux:**

```
posix_memalign(&ptr, 4, 4); // returns 0 if successful
```

Signature (Note order is reversed compares to MSFT):

```
int posix_memalign(void **memptr, size_t alignment, size_t size);
```

Comment: _aligned_malloc is very useful for  this and it can perform a 2 POW N mem align

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE: Your example show the value 4 for both size and alignment. 
 But the actual arguments of _aligned_malloc() and posix_memalign() are reversed: _aligned_malloc( size_t size, size_t alignment ) and posix_memalign(void **memptr, size_t alignment, size_t size). Better give a non

Comment: @AdiShavit Thanks for the comment - I have clarified this in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add 3 to your allocation amount. Allocate the memory. If the returned address isn't already a multiple of 4, round it up until it is. (The most you'd have to round up is 3, which is why you pad your allocation by that much in advance.)

When you free the memory, remember to free the original address, not the rounded-up value.

Comment: you need to add more than 3, as you need space to store the pointer to the start of the block (aka what malloc gave you), you can probably pull it off with 7 bytes min (3 for aligning, 4 for a pointer)

Comment: No need to get so fancy, @Necrolis. You could just store the original pointer in a separate variable, or carry both pointers around in a two-pointer struct.

Comment: You are right rob, that was in my mind before i raise this query. However I have 1000s of such pointer getting passed to 1000 s of fuction as a parameter. So, I could not carry another pointer(7 byte pointer) along with every such pointers.

Answer (score 0):

**Guy Sirton** gave the correct answer, but it is ambiguous and may lead to a potential bug.
The example there shows the value 4 for both *size* and *alignment*.
But the actual arguments of `_aligned_malloc()` and `posix_memalign()` are reversed:

- `_aligned_malloc( size_t size, size_t alignment )`
- `posix_memalign(void **memptr, size_t alignment, size_t size)`

A better example is non-symmetric, e.g.:

```
size_t alignment = 16; // Must be a power of 2
size_t size = 10;      // Not necessarily a power if 2

#ifdef _MSC_VER
  ptr = _aligned_malloc(size, alignment);
#else
  posix_memalign(&ptr, alignment, size); 
#endif
```